# JavaScript/jQuery: Print input in <div> if ... else print in another <div> - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Edit: When I first click the button, the text is printed in the left column (no matter which selection is made). When I click the button again, the text is printed in the right column (again, irrespective of the selection. I really don't get it.

I'm trying to print input from a form into a div. This is the source HTML in need to modify (it's for a university class):

```
 <body>
    <div class="main">
    <h2> Exercise</h2>
        <div class="content">
          <input type="text" class="input">


          <button class="button">Print</button>

          <select>
            <option>Choose left or right</option>
            <option value="left">Left column</option>
            <option value="right">Right column</option>
          </select>

        </div>

        <h4>Output</h4>

        <div id="output"> 

        </div>

        <div class="left">

        </div>
        <div class="right">

        </div>
    </div>
```

There's already some CSS inlcuded in the header:

```
<style>
h3 {font-family: helvetica;}
body {background-color: #ededed;}
.main {margin: auto; margin-top: 100px; font-family: helvetica; max-width: 900px; }
.content {background-color: white; padding: 40px;}
footer {text-align: center;}
#output {background-color: #F2F5F1;}
.left, .right {
  float: left;
  width:  40%;
}
</style>
```

What I need to achieve: text is entered into the field. Next, to the input field, there is an option to select either "left" or "right". Depending on the selection, the input is to be printed either in the left or right part of the screen on the click of a button. This is what I have - but it only prints to the left, no matter the selection. What am I missing?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.input').val();
    if ($('select').val() == "left") {
      $('div.left').html($('.input').val());
    } else {
      $('div.right').html($('.input').val());
    }
  });
});
```

Sorry if this is very basic - I am completely new to JS and jQuery.

Comment: Maybe try to add some padding & border to left, right div and try to reset html content each time.

Comment: `but it only prints to the left, no matter the selection. ` how you come to know it is always printing on left. do you have any css for this? simply assign `left` and `right` classes won't align it automatically. you have to write the style for that. share your css if you have.

Comment: Yes, there is CSS included in the HTML file, but I should be able to get the result only by adding JavaScript/jQuery without changing the HTML/CSS.

Comment: @Laura_Laurent that is fine. we just want to know what is there in the css. if it is not applied from css then we can apply styles through javascript only.

Comment: I just added the css to the original post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Laura_Laurent I have given my answer. check it out.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: Still not working :(  I added some more details to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in your JS, just need basic styling to be done.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button').click(function(){
    $('.input').val();
    if ($('select').val() == "left"){
        $('div.left').html($('.input').val());
        }
    else {
        $('div.right').html($('.input').val());
        }

    });
});
```

```css
h3 {font-family: helvetica;}
body {background-color: #ededed;}
.main {margin: auto; margin-top: 100px; font-family: helvetica; max-width: 900px; }
.content {background-color: white; padding: 40px;}
footer {text-align: center;}
#output {background-color: #F2F5F1;}
.left, .right {
  float: left;
  width:  40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">

<button class="button">Print</button>

<select>

  <option value="left">Left column</option>
  <option value="right">Right column</option>
</select>

<br/>

<div class="left">

</div>
<div class="right">

</div>
```

Comment: CSS was provided by the professor (sorry I did not include in in the original post). Instruction is to neither modify the HTML nor the CSS but to add JS/jQuery to achieve the result. But still - when I enter text in the form, select "right" and click the button, the text is displayed on the left.

Comment: Can I have a look at the given css? That might be the key to your solution

Comment: I don't have access to the file right now, but I'll get back to you later. Thank you so much!

Comment: I added the css to the OP.

Comment: I really don't get it - no matter what I try, it always prints to the left.

Comment: Do you mean text alignment or `div` alignment?

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LtL0qdfx/7/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="button">Print</button>
<select id="columnChange">
    <option value="left">Left column</option>
    <option value="right">Right column</option>
</select>
<div class="printValue"></div>
```

CSS

to make text align left or right base on the classname apply to the printValue element

```
.text-left{ text-align:left; }
.text-right{ text-align:right; }
```

JS

on positionChange first clear previously applied classes `text-left` or `text-right` and addClass based on dropdown value and change the current html on the element.

```
const positionChange = () => {
    $(".printValue")
        .removeClass("text-left")
        .removeClass("text-right");
    $(".printValue")
        .addClass("text-"+$("#columnChange").val())
        .html($(".input").val());
};
```

Two handler bind on change of dropdown value and on button click which call positionChange function once those event trigger.

```
$("#columnChange").on("change", () => {
     positionChange();
});

$(".button").on("click", () => {
    positionChange();
});
```

Comment: Please add an explanation on how it works and how this fixes the OP issue.

Comment: So, I had bind event in input field as well as change event on selection dropdown, so any event trigger which call `positionChange` function that function first clearing the classes added previously for eg: `text-left` or `text-right` later adding class based on drop down value selected and putting value in html of input box

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. But for the view purpose, you didn't see changes happened it in a proper way. The reason behind is the floating elements not started in a new line. You can fix this in many ways.

**If you are ready to modify the HTML then you can use below solution.** Add your float elements inside one `div` like below.

```
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="button">Print</button>
<select>
    <option value="left">Left column</option>
    <option value="right">Right column</option>
</select>
<div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.input').val();    
    if ($('select').val() == "left") {
      $('div.left').html($('.input').val());
    } else {
      $('div.right').html($('.input').val());
    }
  });
```

```css
h3 {font-family: helvetica;}
body {background-color: #ededed;}
.main {margin: auto; margin-top: 100px; font-family: helvetica; max-width: 900px; }
.content {background-color: white; padding: 40px;}
footer {text-align: center;}
#output {background-color: #F2F5F1;}
.left, .right {
  float: left;
  width:  40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="button">Print</button>
<select>
  <option value="left">Left column</option>
  <option value="right">Right column</option>
</select>
<div>
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
</div>
```

**If you don't want to touch the HTML/CSS, you want to achieve it only through the JS then use below solution.** Just add `<br />` or one empty div `<div/>` before the div has class `left` like below.

```
$('div.left').before('<br/>'); //or
$('div.left').before('<div/>');
```

The idea is the same like first solution to start your floating `div` should start with the new line.

```js
$('div.left').before('<br/>');
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.input').val();    
    if ($('select').val() == "left") {      $('div.left').html($('.input').val());
    } else {      $('div.right').html($('.input').val());
    }
  });
```

```css
h3 {font-family: helvetica;}
body {background-color: #ededed;}
.main {margin: auto; margin-top: 100px; font-family: helvetica; max-width: 900px; }
.content {background-color: white; padding: 40px;}
footer {text-align: center;}
#output {background-color: #F2F5F1;}
.left, .right {
  float: left;
  width:  40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="button">Print</button>
<select>
  <option value="left">Left column</option>
  <option value="right">Right column</option>
</select>
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

As per your new structure you have some of the questions.

`When I first click the button, the text is printed in the left column (no matter which selection is made). When I click the button again, the text is printed in the right column (again, irrespective of the selection.`

For fixing the above issue just add `&nbsp;` into your floating div. And do the proper checking in the `if` condition. Because if you didn't select anything from the dropdown, the value of the input is `Choose left or right`. So you have to check the value in both the cases of `if` condition like below.

```js
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.input').val();
    if ($('select').val() == "left") {
      $('div.left').html($('.input').val());
    } else if ($('select').val() == "right"){
      $('div.right').html($('.input').val());
    }
  });
```

```css
h3 {font-family: helvetica;}
body {background-color: #ededed;}
.main {margin: auto; margin-top: 100px; font-family: helvetica; max-width: 900px; }
.content {background-color: white; padding: 40px;}
footer {text-align: center;}
#output {background-color: #F2F5F1; clear:both;}
.left, .right {
  float: left;
  width:40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <h2> Exercise</h2>
        <div class="content">
          <input type="text" class="input">


          <button class="button">Print</button>

          <select>
            <option>Choose left or right</option>
            <option value="left">Left column</option>
            <option value="right">Right column</option>
          </select>

        </div>

        <h4>Output</h4>

      
        <div id="output"> 
          
        </div>

        <div class="left">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. For some reason, it's still not working as expected. :( I added some additional info to the OP.

Comment: updated my answer. check the updates in "EDIT" part.

Answer (score -1):

give a name to select tag

```
<select name="selector">

$('select[name=selector]').val() === "left" )
```